# How to set alter table add column in sql plus

Tags: php, sql

how to set the alter table add column with condition like this as example.
add information about the hobbies possessed by the employees; an employee possesses one or more hobbies, and a hobby is possessed by zero or more employees

How to set alter table to add column with such condition? Sorry, i was still new to the sql query condition.

Comment: Generally speaking, one would have a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) containing `(employee_id, hobby_id)`.

Comment: You want your users to add columns to your table?  That is SO dangerous!  I would recommend creating an additional table to hold the ROWS that would be that COLUMN.

Comment: That mean that it can't be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your explanation, I did this: 
You would have to create 3 tables, it is a many to many relationship, ie an employee to have several hobbies and hobby can be of various employees. A table of employees, other hobbies and other foreign keys with the other two.

```
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `id_employees` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_employees`));

CREATE TABLE `hobbies` (
  `id_hobbies` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` INT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_hobbies`));

CREATE TABLE `employees_hobbies` (
  `id_employees_hobbies` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `id_employees` INT NOT NULL,
  `id_hobbies` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_employees_hobbies`),
  INDEX `fk_employees_hobbies_1_idx` (`id_employees` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_employees_hobbies_2_idx` (`id_hobbies` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_employees_hobbies_1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_employees`)
    REFERENCES `employees` (`id_employees`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_employees_hobbies_2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`id_hobbies`)
    REFERENCES `hobbies` (`id_hobbies`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

If you already have tables and want to change them,

```
ALTER TABLE employees_hobbies ADD id_employees  INT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE employees_hobbies ADD id_hobbies  INT NOT NULL;
ALTER TABLE employees_hobbies ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_employees_hobbies_1`
        FOREIGN KEY (`id_employees`)
        REFERENCES `employees` (`id_employees`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
ALTER TABLE employees_hobbies ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_employees_hobbies_2`
        FOREIGN KEY (`id_hobbies`)
        REFERENCES `hobbies` (`id_hobbies`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION);
```

Instead of `ADD`, you can modify an existing column with `MODIFY`.
Check the source below.

Font:  [Alter Table](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html)

Comment: Thanks Lucas for your explanation. But how can i done it with Alter_Table statement?